# Using url as path for email attachment gets error: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#

I've got a PFD stored with my web host.  I need to send this PDF as an attachment.
I set the attchment = to the URL to the PDF and run the code in VS 2017 is gives me the error: The given path's format is not supported.  I've tried trimming the URL with GetInvalidFileNameChars());  and
GetInvalidPathChars());  but the trimmed URL comes back identical to the original.
My code that generates the error is:

```
string MyPDF = "http://happylandings2018.com/free_ebook_ultimate_weight_loss_bible.pdf";
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(MyPDF);
```

When I set MyPDF equal to the path of the PDF on my system ie. c:/.. it works fine. I'm guessing there must be a simple solution to this, but haven't been able to find anything that works.  Thanks for any replies!

Comment: Attachment doesn’t take a URL, it takes a *file path* to a local document. That’s why you get the error, like documentation says.

Comment: That's the code that's causing the issue, set MyPDF to the URL - set attachment to  MyPDF.  When I run the error goes staight to the line: attachment = new Attachment(MyPDF);

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to the `Attachment` constructor can be the path to a local file, but not a URL. That's why it works when you set it to a file on your system.

If the file is on your server, you can use the `Server.Map()` function to convert the URL of your file to a physical path which you then pass to `Attachement()`. But if you want to use a file from another website, you have to download it to your server first. Something like this:

```
string MyPDF = "http://happylandings2018.com/free_ebook_ultimate_weight_loss_bible.pdf";
var stream = new WebClient().OpenRead(MyPDF);  
Attachment attachement = new Attachment(stream);
```